# Does "adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0" reliably turn off/disable GPS?

Tags: adb

I am trying to completely turn off and disable all GPS and location services for an Android phone.

I found the following ADB command -- "adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0"

Does this completely stop the GPS services from working, including any pinging of any kind to GPS satellites?

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [How to disable GPS on Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249483/44325)

Answer (score 2):

The `location_mode` of the `Secure` settings will disable the Location service until it will be turned on on the settings or by changing the value of the key `location_mode`. ([Checks if location is enabled, based on mode and restrictions.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/location/LocationEnabler.java#135))

Disabling the location mode imply that applications cannot get the fix to access the Location services. **Third-party** applications on Android cannot access the GPS/GNSS hardware, it can access the services of GNSS and Location but not the hardware itself. To access these services, the application need to have the permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` **AND** the Location service must be **enabled**.

On other hand, **system applications** can have access to the GNSS/GPS hardware (permission `LOCATION_HARDWARE`). Thus, there is no guarantee that GNSS/GPS will not be used by the system itself.