# How to disable GPS on Android phone?

Tags: gps

I want to disable all GPS functionality for my Android phone. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: OP's previous question (for additional context): [Does "adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0" reliably turn off/disable GPS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249468/44325)

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Disabling the GPS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/151009/44325), [Can I disable GPS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/95438/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable GPS if not in use?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103937/how-to-disable-gps-if-not-in-use)